# weird behavior of checkbox column after setting a c# datagridview datasource to null

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a c# datagridview checkbox column, which works fine, until i set the datasource to null. The grid collapses, BUT an extra checkbox column gets added immediately to the right of the original.  If I click the reset button again, a third checkbox column pops up.  The code below is standard for this type of column:

[image]

```
chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk);
```

The image shows the result of clicking Reset.

Comment: You say it is called Reset, but the only thing it does is adding a new Column

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you saying you're executing the code in your question and then wondering why there is another checkbox column added? In any case, if you're asking why the Reset method that *you've written* behaves the way it does, you need to post its code.

Comment: Add the entire Reset method so we can see what it does

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, and the code you provided is all there is in the Reset Method, you need to remove the older column first.

I am assuming you only have one column before removing and adding, so I will edit your code to remove it by index first, normally you would want to search for the correct index but this should work in your case:

```
datagrid.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk);
```